# Parameter Map vs IP SLA

Tags: cisco, router

What is the difference between parameter map and ip sla? In both we can specify that if threshold of something is crossed then a log is generated and based on that some action can be taken. Has one got more options than another or serves some other purpose?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

`parameter-map` and `ip sla` do different things.

> A parameter map allows you to specify parameters that control the
>   behavior of actions and match criteria specified under a policy map
>   and a class map, respectively.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/security/m1/sec-m1-cr-book/sec-cr-p1.html#wp2265051128

(both are very long subjects to begin to explain)

Comment: Can you provide me a small explanation about their differences, if possible?